# Javascript - Window open, use CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cdn, window.open

Simple question.
I cannot get a new opened window to use CSS.

```
var previewWindow = window.open();
$(previewWindow.document.body).append(data);
```

The data is just a stringbuilder generating html from our backend.

The problem is, I want the newly opened tab/window to use Twitter bootstrap, either CDN or use the file.

I cannot get it to work with, what I tought should be the solution

```
$(previewWindow.document.head).append('cdn or path goes here')
```

I cannot seem to find anyone else with this problem, or I need a lecture in Google.

[image: head]

As you can see, in the head the CDN is properly added. But the html isn't using any of the CSS.

Comment: What here is the value of data? Why are you loading cdn script twice? And why body to insert second css link tag?

Comment: The value of data is pure HTML.
   Like: `<div class="col-12">` and so on. So what you see in body, except the <link> tag.
Thats just a test. Ive been testing around with different solutions found on strange sites.

Comment: Are you opening a URL with `window.open()` or are you doing it just as above?

Comment: @Archer No predefined URL. So its just a about:blank page.

Comment: Thanks - it was the suggestion below that made me ask, and that's sparked a conversation about the very thing now!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using protocol-relative URLs.

However, since you don't pass a URL to `window.open()`, it displays `about:blank`.

Therefore, it tries to load `about://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/...`, which doesn't exist.

You should use absolute URLs that include a protocol.

Comment: Oh. Well, it didn't even struck my mind. I will try that. Thanks!


As a temporary solution before this answer, I get the CSS content from file and add it inside `<style></style>` tag.

Comment: Is there a suggested method for getting round this, rather than using URLs with protocols?  The only thing that springs to mind is open a local page and write to that (maybe a blank dummy page, specifically for this purpose) but that sounds a bit "hacky".

Comment: @Archer: AFAIK, opening a blank page from your server is the only solution.  (you can add heavy cache headers)

Comment: That was my first solution. Adding and using a dummypage and appending the HTML on that.
But I couldn't stop there.
But as you said, its the last resort. Well, maybe the solution is better then inline styling ;)

Comment: @SLaks couldn't base tag used to just specified a protocol?